# Rails - d3-tip gem not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I'm using the d3 gem, and I'm trying to add the d3-tip gem (https://github.com/lorennorman/d3-tip-rails).  The instructions say that the D3 library should be loaded before requiring d3-tip.  I have this in application.js:

```
//= require d3
//= require d3-tip
```

Is there something else I should doing besides this, and having both in my Gemfile?  I am getting this error what I trying to define a tooltip:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I came across a blog post regarding the same problem (https://hendrixski.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/d3-tip-was-borked-in-require-js-undefined-is-not-a-function-ggrr/) but I am not entirely sure how to implement the workaround described.

Can someone shed a little light?

Comment: I'd create an issue within the GitHub repository for d3-tip; noone will know this code better than @lorennorman